linux find command, using delete and prune gives error
I'm trying to scan a backup drive and remove files older than about two years. However, there is one folder I want to be skipped, as it is where the needed older files go.
Here's the command I tried to use:
find /mnt/backup/ -path '/mnt/backup/home/shares/Projects/Projects Archive' -prune -o -atime +731 -type f -delete*
I get the result below:
find: The -delete action automatically turns on -depth, but -prune does nothing when -depth is in effect.  If you want to carry on anyway, just explicitly use the -depth option.
It seems find may be a dead end for this task, but am hoping someone might have some insight into how to work around this.
Thanks in advance.
B

different approach to exclude the specific folder while deleting files older than two years
find /mnt/backup/ -path '/mnt/backup/home/shares/Projects/Projects Archive' -prune -o -atime +731 -type f -exec rm {} \;

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-explicitly-exclude-directory-from-find-command-s-search

I guess the find "-delete" option isn't really going to work. Your approach is the most elegant alternative, basically substituting "rm {}" for delete option and avoiding the peculiar logic find applies to -prune and -delete.
I'm curious what the ";" at the end is for? I have found similar find scripts, so I know it is typical.

@bkeahl ; terminates the -exec expression. To understand the backslash, see the beginning of this answer.

I don't understand find well enough to know if there's a more elegant solution, but you could do something like this:
find /mnt/backup -atime +731 | \ 
grep --null --invert-match '/mnt/backup/home/shares/Projects/Projects Archive' | \ 
xargs -0 -n 10 rm -r

This runs find to find the old files, removes files in the pruned path using grep, then uses xargs and rm -r to delete them. It's not ideal because depending on depth vs breadth behavior of find, it might delete a folder recursively, then try to delete a file in that folder which was already deleted. I like this style of compound command because instead of running the rm -r command you can run echo, to debug the script and make sure it's running as expecting before committing.
